# iOS webapp status bar inconsistent

Tags: ios, web-applications, statusbar, iphone-standalone-web-app

While making a web app I tried to make the status bar transparant but reading through tons of documentation I figured this was deprecated and used `default` with this as result:

[image: screenshot1 - white status bar]

Quite a while in the development process it suddenly changed to this:

[image: screenshot2 - transparent status bar]

and in that one instance it keeps working, no matter how much I reload everything. But I cannot get it to work in other instances.

this is the code in my header on index.php

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/appiconTAD.png">
<!-- <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/splashScreen.png"> -->
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>take a dare</title>
<link href="css/style.css?v1" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/main.css?v1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any Ideas?

worth noting that I am on IOS dev beta 11.5

Comment: Paste the `<head>` code if you can.

Comment: @nathan posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like in iOS 11 status bar doesn't overlap the content anymore when set to **black-translucent**. So the status shows your apps background-color.

Comment: That would be awesome but sad for non ios11 users

Comment: I experimentet a little with that and found some odd behaviour. The status bar does take up 20px and content seems to scroll beneath it. A fixed positioned element with top -20px is cut off by the status bar. The content still scrolls beneath the status bar and is visible.

Comment: Pushing a fixed position element beneath the status bar with translateY(-20px) will only show it when content scrolls beneath it.